# is this a good design

Tags: design, c++, object-oriented-design

For example, I have a clan and a character. There's a character that is the leader. To give the clan a specific feature, some money from the character is required.

I don't want to have too much tight coupling. Right now I have a member in the `clan` class like this:

```
bool clan::give_rank(character* chr, int rank)
{ 
    if (!is_leader(chr.id()) || !chr->has_money(500))
       return false;

    this->rank_ = rank;
    chr->take_money(500); 
    return true;
}
```

Is this tight coupling? or maybe I should have a secondary class like a clan_mgr that connects both classes?

```
bool clan_mngr::give_rank(character* chr, int rank)
{ 
    clan* myclan = chr->get_clan(); 

    if (!myclan || !myclan->is_leader(chr.id()) || !chr->has_money(500))
       return false;

    myclan->rank_ = rank;
    chr->take_money(500);
    return true;
}
```

// Or maybe this one, which looks even worse imo:

```
bool character::give_rank_to_clan(int rank)
{ 
    clan* myclan = chr->get_clan(); 

    if (!myclan || !myclan->is_leader(id()) || !has_money(500))
       return false;

    myclan->rank_ = rank;
    TakeMoney(500);    
    return true;
}
```

Comment: As a sidenote you should move the has_money into the TakeMoney method (or a separate PayMoney method) if (PayMoney(500)) SetRank

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach look good. Clan/character is a container relashionship and so the ideal approach would be the Clan has a list of members, and the character is unaware of Clan class. That means character's API must be designed so Clan can implement its services.